# WCF how to send username token to WCF service

Tags: wcf

In a WSE3.0 web service, in order for me to call any methods of the web service I needed to set the client credentials to a UsernameToken object. How is this done from the client application for a WCF service?

Answer (score 2):

This totally depends on the security settings on your WCF service:

- if you use **Windows** client credentials, you don't have to do anything; your Windows credentials will be passed to and checked by the WCF service automagically
- if you use **Certificates** to secure your callers, you need to make sure the certificate is installed in the right place and the client is configured properly to send that certificate
- if you use **Username** client credentials, then you need to set the user name and password in your WCF client code - and you can only set it in code, there's currently no way to configure this in config:

  ```
  YourWCFClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "Your-User-Name-Here";
  YourWCFClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "top$secret";
  ```

Comment: +1, though I get freaked out that the all-time top user for WCF uses the term "automagically". :-)

Comment: *Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic.* (by Arthur C. Clarke) :-)

Comment: How is the username and password sent to the WCF service? Is it included in the soap message? How would I retrieve the user credential on the WCF service in order to programmatically do impersonation to call a stored procedure?